# What can I do with the white parts of kale?

Tags: kale

I like to bake, fry, cook and make salads out of dark green parts of the kale. But when I get to the middle of the kale, I don't like those whiteish bright parts, just not tasty much imo.

I was thinking about blending it in a smoothie but I don't have a blender yet.

Any ideas how to prepare those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I found over time:

Chop it into tiny pieces and stir fry it with bacon and onions (also chopped up). Once that's soft, leave it to cool, then mix it in meatballs in a 50:50 ratio. If some eggs and breadcrumbs are added a fine meatball is made that tastes a bit sweeter and veggy and is healthier. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just like the tougher parts of any brassica plant (e.g. broccoli), chop the stems as thinly as required and add to a stir fry dish. they typically take as long as carrots take to "cook" in the wok

Properly grown kale with a decent frost exposure, should have a softer stems with a sweeter and more flavourful taste

Comment: I kinda like that dark taste from the green parts. :D

Answer (score 1):

I love taking the stems from broccoli and doing a quick 'pickle'. First, I peel the stems to reveal the inner white parts. I typically make long rectangles of the stems, which I then julienne. After that, I soak them in rice vinegar with a pinch of salt and freshly ground pepper. You can add a drop or two of Cholula Chili Lime hot sauce, which adds another layer of flavor. Serve after 'pickling' in the liquid for at least 10 minutes. Works great with meaty dishes.

I would imagine you could do the same with the kale's white parts. As a matter of fact - I will have to try when I get some good quality kale.